# Access denied for user when using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE : Ubuntu to RDS- MYSQL

Tags: mysql, bash, file-upload, ubuntu-14.04

When executing this LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE statement I get the following problems. I am running this statement on an Ubuntu server using bash. All other queries to the database work fine. However the LOAD DATA INFILE statement fails every time.

I have tried the following as suggested in other forums. However this hasn't worked.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO USERNAME@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'SECURE' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

This is the Statement executed in BASH:

```
$(mysql -h "$host" --user="$user" --password="$pw" --local-infile=1 -D"$DbName" --skip-column-names -e "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/html/results/F9_result.jtl' INTO TABLE `result.jtl` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' IGNORE 1 LINES;")
```

Error Message

```
Access denied for user 'USERNAME'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're granting `ALL PRIVILEGES` to databases with just one character in their name  .... `%.*` does that.

Try `GRANT FILE ON *.* TO` whomever.

Also notice that you're changing that user's password to the oxymoronic value `SECURE`.